# Why on hover color is not filling

Tags: html, css

I want a button on which when we hover a transaction of filling of white colour and the text inside gets blue colour

this is my HTML CSS for that button

```
 .working-btn-white button {
  height:60px;
  width:155px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius:30px;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  color:#fff;
  outline:none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .working-btn-white button span {
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  line-height: 60px;
 }
 .working-btn-white button span:hover{
    color: #337ab7;
    font-weight: bold;

 }
 .working-btn-white button span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  left:-100%;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  transition:left 0.25s ease;
  z-index:-1
 }
 .working-btn-white button span:hover::after {
  left:0%;
  color:white;
 }


my html   

<div class="working-btn-white">
                <button><span>Get a Quote</span></button>
                <button><span>View our Work</span></button>
               </div>
```

but it does not filling the white colour in background you can check similar effect here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BXoJbX but i need white color instead of this gradient fill

Comment: Well @Avinash, it does have white color in background on hover see here: https://jsbin.com/xagesexico/edit?html,css,output (same code as yours)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9y46v1p3/1/ here is a jsfiddle with your code... im not sure what you are talking about, can you clarify? also i added a black border to the buttons so we can see them

Comment: remove   background: transparent;  and check, but not exactly sure what you want your final result

Comment: Hi @Avinash, in your code I have added background color so we can see the animation of white background

Comment: hover a transaction of filling of white color will not be visible if your background if your background is also white...

Comment: @RobS. my code is working fine on jsfiddle but when i am using it on my developing enviroment the hover effect is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because your z-index property does not work on it as it is position:absolute so you need to give your parent dive as opacity less then one(let's say.99)  then I think it would work for you.  You can use this link to see further https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 1):

This is your Solution

```css
body{
  background-color: green;
}

.working-btn-white button {
  height:60px;
  width:155px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius:30px;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  border-color: black;
  color:#fff;
  outline:none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .working-btn-white button span {
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  line-height: 60px;
 }
 .working-btn-white button span:hover{
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
 .working-btn-white button span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  left:-100%;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  transition:left 0.25s ease;
  z-index:-1
 }
 .working-btn-white button span:hover::after {
  left:0%;
  color:white;
 }
```

```html
<div class="working-btn-white">
  <button><span>Get a Quote</span></button>
  <button><span>View our Work</span></button>
 </div>
```

See Code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/cqu7hymd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done but littlebit changes are thereI think following CSS Code will help you.

```
.working-btn-white button {
   height:60px;
   width:155px;
   font-weight: bold;
   background: #f1f1f1;
   border-radius:30px;
   border:2px solid #f2f2f2;
   color:#fff;
   outline:none;
   position: relative;
   margin: 25px;
   overflow: hidden;
 }

 .working-btn-white button:hover {  
   background: #fff;
   color:blue;
 }
```

Comment: it is actually just filling it but i want an effect of filling from left to right

Answer (score 0):

Just add some dark color to your body because your button color is white and if your background is also white then the button will not be visible.so change your body color or div background color.

Either  use one of them:

```
  body{background-color:#c7c7c7;}
```

or

```
   div{background-color:#c7c7c7;}
```

check out my code, just i added `background-color:#c7c7c7;` to body element.

```css
 body{
 background-color:#c7c7c7;
 }
 
 
 .working-btn-white button {
  height:60px;
  width:155px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius:30px;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  color:#fff;
  outline:none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .working-btn-white button span {
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  line-height: 60px;
 }
 .working-btn-white button span:hover{
    color: #337ab7;
    font-weight: bold;

 }
 .working-btn-white button span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  left:-100%;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  transition:left 0.25s ease;
  z-index:-1
 }
 .working-btn-white button span:hover::after {
  left:0%;
  color:white;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="working-btn-white">
                <button><span>Get a Quote</span></button>
                <button><span>View our Work</span></button>
               </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @AmareshSM  ji can you tell me the reason why my code is not working